# Change Build Display Name after a build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is it possible to change the Build Display Name after a build has already been built?
I want to use it the following way:

1)Schedule a build with any build display name (ex. #65)

2)Promote that build so that it is tagged using a parameter as the name for the tag

3)Change the build display name to the tag name (ex. TST_08-04-2014)

I've looked at Build Name Setter and Version Number, but neither of those seem to be able to change the Build Display Name **After** a build.
Right now I have to manually click the build and then click "Edit Build Information." I would prefer to not have to do this manually.

Comment: When do you want to promote the build and change the build name? Immediately after the build or sometime later after the build?

Comment: The promotion of a build happens sometime later. The build is selected and then promoted manually. When it is selected and promoted manually, I want the build name to change manually.